# Importing Confluence site into TWiki: conversion script breaks at SSL certificate

Tags: confluence, twiki

I am trying to migrate from a local install Confluence site into TWiki. TWiki provides a migration tool "ConfluenceToTWikiAddon", although it is dated 2008. Nevertheless I tried to give it a shot. I installed the Perl modules as per the requirements of the tool, and launched the script. I fails complaining of the SSL certificate (which seems to be in order):

```html
[root@twikihost:~/Downloads/ConfluenceToTWikiAddon/src] # perl -I ../lib -I /var/www/html/twiki/lib genTWikiWeb.pl
NOTE: Home directory not specified on the command line,
                 finding from the current directory.
INFO - START:XML Extraction
INFO - START:XML Extraction continued for
500 Can't connect to confluencehost:443 (certificate verify failed) at genTWikiWeb.pl line 123.
 at /usr/local/share/perl5/SOAP/Lite.pm line 3644.
        SOAP::Lite::__ANON__(XMLRPC::Lite=HASH(0x5608907794c0), "\x{a}not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 3, byte 3 "...) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/SOAP/Lite.pm line 3833
        SOAP::Lite::call(XMLRPC::Lite=HASH(0x5608907794c0), "confluence1.login", "(REDACTED USERNAME)", "(REDACTED_PWD)") called at genTWikiWeb.pl line 123
        main::extractSpaces() called at genTWikiWeb.pl line 49
```

I'm looking for any clues on how to get past this.
Thanks!